# writing inline jquery in wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to write a small jquery code block through a wordpress post? I would like that script to execute in the post. I am trying this just by dropping it by wrapping it under a script tag but when I am looking at the source I am seeing each line is wrapped in a

tag. How should I resolve this? I would imagine there should be a setting in the editor to allow me to pass inline jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can make some hack by disable Visual Editor. `Users > Your Profile > Disable the visual editor when writing`.

Voilla. Now you have plain text editor, where none of your code will be modified by the editor.

After save that post, you can enable it back.

Comment: didnt really work...the visual editor is gone but the <p> tag is still wrapping each line of  the js block

Comment: Ouh ya. The `<p>` tag (or sometime `<br />` tag) was add automatically by wordpress, and not from Visual Editor. You need to disabled wpautop filter. Check this url at `Disabling the filter`  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter

Comment: if you want to get rid of p tag trim spaces and next lines in your `<script>` tags. or i should say minify it.